# io.Copy does not work without the sleep + golang sftp-proxy

Tags: go

Hello people I'm looking to understand the project https://github.com/Freeaqingme/SSHalama/ an SFTP proxy.

And I stumble upon this code

```
    go s.pipeRequests(psChannel, sChannel, psRequests, sRequests)
    time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)
    go s.pipe(sChannel, psChannel)
    go s.pipe(psChannel, Channel)
```

Over here the `time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)` is extremely crucial ignore that the SFTP session get established but no PTTY appear.

The full code looks like this.

```
  func (s *Server) handleChannel(newChannel ssh.NewChannel, rClient *ssh.Client) {
    if newChannel.ChannelType() != "session" {
        newChannel.Reject(ssh.UnknownChannelType, "unknown channel type: "+newChannel.ChannelType())
        return
    }
    psChannel, psRequests, err := newChannel.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        panic("could not accept channel.")
    }

    sChannel, sRequests, err := rClient.OpenChannel(newChannel.ChannelType(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to create session: " + err.Error())
    }

    go s.pipeRequests(psChannel, sChannel, psRequests, sRequests)
    time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)
    go s.pipe(sChannel, psChannel)
    go s.pipe(psChannel, sChannel)
}
    
func (s *Server) pipe(dst, src ssh.Channel) {
    _, err := io.Copy(dst, src)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }

    dst.CloseWrite()
}
```

I want to understand why the **sleep**(`time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)`) is so essential for the SFTP session to work and have  PTTY appear.

Comment: It shouldn't be crucial, it's almost certainly a hacky workaround to a real issue that should be solved by correctly detecting and signaling readiness.

Comment: @Adrian can you elaborate that as an answer.

Comment: @Adrian want to give it another shot as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)
```

gives enough time for data arrive on `psChannel`, so when copy is triggered, there is reference to read.

usually pipes are synchronous, although you can achieve async operations it may end up with such hack ways to that tho. an elegant form to achieve what is in the code is [using go pipes](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Pipe)

as the code says it will exchange data between two channels, a <-> b. if nothing arrives on the first, the whole program cannot work properly. the `time.Sleep` ensures that readiness. not only, the underlying ssh implementation in use requires a handshake otherwise the server hangs, this might give a fraction of delay.

this implementation btw relies on the example from [the ssh NewServerConn doc](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#NewServerConn)

Comment: As you will have noticed, posting junk as a placeholder will tend to attract downvotes which could easily have been avoided.

Comment: @tripleee shame on me and I felt a lot the effect :/ this was a dumb attempt to check if I was able to give answers, as I am not yet for comments. well newbie on stackoverflow ux here... learning by the mistakes :(

Comment: @WesleyVicthor Thanks for answering the question I have a follow-up question What  `io.Copy` states it reads from the source until an EOF is detected. So essentially the checking for `fd` **readiness is something that io.Copy would do, right?**

Like my intrigued example [https://play.golang.org/p/RFUVQmRQS1I](https://play.golang.org/p/RFUVQmRQS1I) wherein I deliberately ask the writer to wait for 2 sec meanwhile the io.Copy is waiting for r `*pipe.Reader` to be available/ready to read

Comment: @Noobie in your example what we are seeing is the effect of `io.Pipe` usage, as it uses channels  and blocks until a write arrives. this is not `io.Copy` feature.  here is an example without pipe: https://play.golang.org/p/8mtxNn584ot that is what makes `io.Pipe` the right candidate for the implementation above, https://golang.org/pkg/io/#PipeReader.Read

Comment: @WesleyVicthor One last thing you are saying the above code can be used using IO.pipe.  Thanks a ton for the answer.